# How do I call a python scipt by php on a less powerful server to be run on an other more powerful server (cluster)?

Tags: php, python, cluster-computing

I have a action.php script from where I call a python script like this:

```
$call_python = "../python/python myPythonScript.py ".$someArgument;
$python_output = Null; // stores every output generated by myPythonScript.py
$mystring = exec($call_python, $output_python);
```

I know, this is perhaps not the best way, but it works for me so far. Recently I discovered, that the computational power of the actual server is not sufficient. So I want the python script to be run on a  more powerful server (a cluster) which is in the same network.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily replace your `exec()` call with [`ssh2_exec()`](http://php.net/ssh2_exec). To get the output use `stream_get_context()` however. That's probably the sanest solution here.

You just need to open a connection to your secondary server beforehand. See  [`ssh2_connect`](http://php.net/ssh2_connect) and [`ssh2_auth_password`](http://php.net/ssh2_auth_password) for that. And of course you need the ssh2 PHP extension installed and enabled.

Comment: You speak of sanity. =) May I ask you what the "professional way" would be to solve my problem?

Comment: I think this is already an acceptable solution security-wise. If you optimize for speed however, you could make your script on the second server an `inetd` or `nc -l -k` service. Just don't forget some /etc/hosts.allow and .deny settings for that.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that tomorrow. Hopefully it will work this way!